# How can I define my ItemReader : Spring batch, JPA

Tags: java, spring

I want to implement a batch that will read the data from a database and processed to insert into another database. 
How can i define my ItemReader? example? knowing that I use jpa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [spring-batch-samples](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/spring-batch-samples/) project. The [ioSample job](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/spring-batch-samples/index.html#ioSample) has a JPA definition:

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/iosample/jpa.xml

Here's the relevant part:

```
<bean id="itemReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="queryString" value="select c from CustomerCredit c" />
</bean>
```